# Trigger to update grandparent field

Tags: apex, trigger

I am creating a trigger in which relationship goes like this....
`opportunity` is the grandparent it has a child `Invoice` and further Invoice has a child `Invoice Line`..

Now what i need is When I create an `Invoice Line` and select a   `procedure_type__c`(it is a picklist) then the same value goes in `Opportunity.Type` .

```
trigger UpdateProcedureType on Invoice_Line__c (after insert)   
{  
    List<Invoice_Line__c> invoiceLineItemsList = new List<Invoice_Line__c>();  
    List<Invoice__c> invoiceList = new List<Invoice__c>();  
    invoiceList = [Select id, name, Invoice__c.opportunity.id,
                               (Select id, name From Invoice_Line__c) From Invoice__c];    
    for(Invoice__c inv : trigger.new)  
    {  
        Invoice_Line__c invoiceLine = new Invoice_Line__c();  
        inv.opportunity.Type = invoiceLine.Procedure_Type__c;  
    }  

}
```

Comment: yes let me paste my code here....my approach is Wrong, and I couldnt figure out how to do it..

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in trigger like:

```
Update new Opportunity(Id = objInvoiceLine.Invoice.Opportunity, 
                       Type = objInvoiceLine.procedure_type__c);
```

### Updates

```
trigger UpdateProcedureType on Invoice_Line__c (after insert)   
{  
    List<Invoice_Line__c> invoiceLineItemsList = new List<Invoice_Line__c>();  
    List<Invoice__c> invoiceList = new List<Invoice__c>();

    map<Id, Invoice_Line__c> mapInvoiceLine = new map<Id, Invoice_Line__c>([Select id, name, Invoice__r.Opportunity.Id 
                                                                              From Invoice_Line__c 
                                                                             WHERE Id IN: Trigger.New ]);
    List<Opportunity> lstOpportunity = new List<Opportunity>();
    for(Invoice_Line__c invline : trigger.new)  
    {  
        if( String.isNotEmpty(invline.Procedure_Type__c) && mapInvoiceLine.get(invline.Id).Invoice__r.Opportunity.Id != null){
            lstOpportunity.add(new Opportunity(Id = mapInvoiceLine.get(invline.Id).Invoice.Invoice__r.Opportunity.Id, 
                           Type = invline.Procedure_Type__c));
        }
    }  
    update lstOpportunity;
}
```

Comment: error invalid foreign key

Comment: @Anzar check updated ans

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Didn't understand relationship 'Invoices__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 6 column 76

Comment: I am getting this error.....

Comment: @Anzar  check relationship name

Comment: Relationship name is Invoices

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger is on the Invoice_Line__c object, not on the Invoice__c object. So writing for(Invoice__c in : trigger.new) is incorrect, because trigger.new is of type Invoice_Line__c not of type Invoice. First, I suggest that you create a formula field on the Invoice_Line__c object to get the Id of the grandparent opportunity. The formula would be something like this:

```
Invoice__r.Opportunity__c.
```

Let's suppose that this field exists and its name is opportunity__c. Now, you cen use the follwoing code:

```
trigger UpdateProcedureType on Invoice_Line__c (after insert) {  
    Map<Id, Opportunity> map_opps = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
    for (Invoice_Line__c invLine: Trigger.new) {
        map_opps.put(invLine.Id, new Opportunity(Id = invLine.opportunity__c));
    }

    // Update grandparent opportunities
    for (Integer i = 0; i < trigger.new.size(); i++) {
        Opportunity tempOpp = map_opps.get(trigger.new[i].Id);
        tempOpp.Type = trigger.new[i].procedure_type__c;
        map_opps.put(trigger.new[i].Id, tempOpp);
    }

    update map_opps.values();
}
```

Comment: You can even optimize this code by using only one for loop. But to keep it clear I preferred to use 2 loops.

Comment: line `Id = invLine.opportunity__c` wrong. Parent is Opportunity --> Invoice --> invoice line.. Trigger on Invoice Line then .. Trigger.New will return Invoice Line but you are accessing `Id = invLine.opportunity__c`

Comment: Yes you're right, that's why I suggested to create a formula field on the Invoice_Line__c object, named Opportunity__c, and it would contain the Id of the grand parent. The formula field would make the trigger easier to implement, and it saves a SOQL query as you don't have to query for the opportunity Id.

Comment: Without formula we can do that check above Nilesh Ans.

Comment: Yes, it is correct too, but it uses a SOQL query to construct the mapInvoiceLine map, in order to grab the grand parent Id. The formula does exactly that and saves you a SOQL query. I know it is not a big deal, I just offered an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

First of think your trigger is wrong because Trigger.new will return Invoice_Line__c not Invoice__c  on your below code.

//Wrong Code

```
 for(*Invoice__c* inv : trigger.new)  
 {  
       Invoice_Line__c invoiceLine = new Invoice_Line__c();  
       inv.opportunity.Type = invoiceLine.Procedure_Type__c;  
 }
```

Right Code

```
for(*Invoice_Line__c* inv : trigger.new)  
{  
      Invoice_Line__c invoiceLine = new Invoice_Line__c();  
      inv.opportunity.Type = invoiceLine.Procedure_Type__c;  

}
```

And then write your logic to update opportunity Type like below code.

```
trigger UpdateProcedureType on Invoice_Line__c (after insert)   
{  
    List<Invoice_Line__c> invoiceLineItemsList = new List<Invoice_Line__c>();  
    List<Invoice__c> invoiceList = new List<Invoice__c>();  
    invoiceList = [Select id, name, Invoice__c.opportunity.id,
                               (Select id, name From Invoice_Line__c) From Invoice__c]; 
List<Opportunity> listOpp = new List<Opportunity>();   
    for(Invoice_Line__c inv : trigger.new)  
    {  
        Invoice_Line__c invoiceLine = new Invoice_Line__c();  
        if(invoiceLine.Procedure_Type__c != null)
        {
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
            opp.id = inv.Invoice.Opportunity;
            opp.Type = objInvoiceLine.procedure_type__c; 
            oppList.add(opp);
        }
    }  
update oppList;
}
```

Comment: So we can get relationship field value in Trigger.new i.e `inv.Invoice.Opportunity` ?

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Didn't understand relationship 'Invoices__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 5 column 19

Answer (score 1):

The trigger is on Invoice_Line__c. Trigger.new will always return list of Invoice_Line__c records. So your code is not correct. 
And also you can't get/assign relationship field value in the loop which process Trigger.new list.

```
for(Invoice__c inv : trigger.new)  
{  
    Invoice_Line__c invoiceLine = new Invoice_Line__c();  
    inv.opportunity.Type = invoiceLine.Procedure_Type__c;  
}
```

Trigger should be written to process bulk records. Trigger.new will have maximum of 200 records at a time.Just check the below code and try like this.

```
trigger UpdateProcedureType on Invoice_Line__c (after insert)  {  

    Set<Id> InvoiceIdSet = new Set<Id>();

    //Collect all Invoice ids in the set from Invoice Line Item.
    for(Invoice_Line__c inv : trigger.new)  { 
        if(inv.Invoice__c != NULL) InvoiceIdSet.add(inv.Invoice__c);
    }

    if(InvoiceIdSet.size() > 0) {

        //query against Invoice__c using the above set and will return required results instead of querying all records from database. and stored that in the map with key as Invoice Id.
        Map<Id,Invoice__c>  invoiceMap = new Map<Id,Invoice__c>([Select id, name, opportunity__r.id From Invoice__c WHERE Id IN :InvoiceIdSet  ]);

        Map<Id,Opportunity> oppListToUpdateMap = new Map<Id,Opportunity>();

        for(Invoice_Line__c invLI : trigger.new)  { 
            if(invLI.Procedure_Type__c!= NULL){

                //check the Invoice record in the map
                if(invoiceMap.containsKey(invLI.Invoice__c ) && invoiceMap.get(invLI.Invoice__c ).opportunity__r.Id != NULL){ 

                    Opprotunity opp = new Opportunity(Id = invoiceMap.get(invLI.Invoice__c ).opportunity__r.Id);
                    opp.Type=invLI.Procedure_Type__c;
                    oppListToUpdateMap.put(opp.Id,opp); //use map instead of list to collect the opportunity to update.So that Even if more than one record inserted,DUPLICATE_VALUE error won't occur.
                }
            }

        }  

        if(oppListToUpdateMap.size() > 0 && oppListToUpdateMap.values.size() > 0) update oppListToUpdateMap.values(); //update opportunity records
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i m getting this error  
Error: Compile Error: Didn't understand relationship 'opportunity__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 13 column 65

Comment: Check API name of Opportunity field on Invoice__c Object and use that in the Invoice__c query.